# How to remove ids from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying through the array and use a `Array.prototype.filter()` method on every `children` array to find the elements whose key matches with the ones specified.

Then, I'am using `Array.prototype.splice()` to remove the results from the respective `children` array but the result is return `undefined`.

```js
const inputArray = [
  "Oxygen-a3b8be32-c36e-a02e-37f4-a35239e0cedb",
  "633ac872e78fa7ebee03b8bf",
  "5e69dbd7-5fee-67a9-c73f-4656f9b90715",
  "d484558b-4717-b0b8-db07-68288afb4f6a",
  "63922aac4ff08f52d71fa891",
  "33a3182b-93a4-84b9-4c49-c955a8416197",
];

const originalArray = [{
    title: "Animals",
    key: "d484558b-4717-b0b8-db07-68288afb4f6a",
    children: [{
      title: "Color",
      key: "63922aac4ff08f52d71fa891",
      children: [{
          title: "Black",
          key: "Black-9e994ed2-823b-d1d6-4613-91d43f570fec",
        },
        {
          title: "White",
          key: "White-5d0b102a-2555-8f7c-d471-cc82a5bd9c01",
        },
      ],
    }, ],
  },
  {
    title: "Elements",
    key: "5e69dbd7-5fee-67a9-c73f-4656f9b90715",
    children: [{
      title: "Non metals",
      key: "633ac872e78fa7ebee03b8bf",
      children: [{
          title: "Carbon",
          key: "Carbon-e443daa4-def4-9830-796e-ee8c5a1f41d4",
        },
        {
          title: "Nitrogen",
          key: "Nitrogen-c2922569-0b2d-0e07-454d-d8411af701b7",
        },
        {
          title: "Oxygen",
          key: "Oxygen-a3b8be32-c36e-a02e-37f4-a35239e0cedb",
        },
      ],
    }, ],
  },
  {
    title: "Planets",
    key: "33a3182b-93a4-84b9-4c49-c955a8416197",
    children: [{
      title: "Composition",
      key: "63b3d5cd12c06ba7ce353f76",
      children: [{
          title: "Chthonian planet",
          key: "Chthonian planet-b3c593c1-d29e-5e14-1b11-2241e8ef2be6",
        },
        {
          title: "Carbon planet",
          key: "Carbon planet-07d67d62-afcf-fbcf-a8e8-75081cb44c2f",
        },
      ],
    }, ],
  },
];

console.log(
  " ~ file: TranferTree.misc.js:152 ~ onCheck ~ outputArray",
  originalArray.forEach(e => {
    e.children.forEach((c, i) => {
      if (inputArray.includes(c.key)) {
        e.children.splice(i, 1);
      } else {
        c.children.forEach((cc, j) => {
          if (inputArray.includes(cc.key)) {
            c.children.splice(j, 1);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  })
);
```

Note: For example in the `Elements => 5e69dbd7-5fee-67a9-c73f-4656f9b90715` children `Non metals => 633ac872e78fa7ebee03b8bf` i am only remove `object` with this `key` => `Oxygen-a3b8be32-c36e-a02e-37f4-a35239e0cedb` I want to keep the other objects that were not found this also applies to for example `Composition => 63b3d5cd12c06ba7ce353f76` or `Planets => 33a3182b-93a4-84b9-4c49-c955a8416197`.

Comment: do you need the same object reference?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, this function will work as an `add` and `remove` items so that later I can `submit` check this print https://imgur.com/a/SVV3OYH

Comment: You're logging the result from `forEach`, which is always `undefined`. Don't you mean to log the modified array, `originalArray`?

Comment: @RichardDunn Yes, I want to register the changes in `originalArray`

Comment: do you want an empty array? what result do you expect?

Comment: It's already working, you're just not logging it. You're logging the return value from `forEach`, which is _always_ `undefined`. Just run `console.log(originalArray)`

Comment: @RichardDunn Yesss, you right bro should have paid more attention... Submit in as soluction i am mark was resolved! ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to preserve the original object references it will be slightly less efficient, but here's a way you can do it with recursive function calls. It provides the same output as your code, but it's correctly logging the final structure whereas yours is logging the return value of `.forEach()` which is undefined, by design.

```js
const inputArray = [
  "Oxygen-a3b8be32-c36e-a02e-37f4-a35239e0cedb",
  "633ac872e78fa7ebee03b8bf",
  "5e69dbd7-5fee-67a9-c73f-4656f9b90715",
  "d484558b-4717-b0b8-db07-68288afb4f6a",
  "63922aac4ff08f52d71fa891",
  "33a3182b-93a4-84b9-4c49-c955a8416197",
];

const originalArray = [{
    title: "Animals",
    key: "d484558b-4717-b0b8-db07-68288afb4f6a",
    children: [{
      title: "Color",
      key: "63922aac4ff08f52d71fa891",
      children: [{
          title: "Black",
          key: "Black-9e994ed2-823b-d1d6-4613-91d43f570fec",
        },
        {
          title: "White",
          key: "White-5d0b102a-2555-8f7c-d471-cc82a5bd9c01",
        },
      ],
    }, ],
  },
  {
    title: "Elements",
    key: "5e69dbd7-5fee-67a9-c73f-4656f9b90715",
    children: [{
      title: "Non metals",
      key: "633ac872e78fa7ebee03b8bf",
      children: [{
          title: "Carbon",
          key: "Carbon-e443daa4-def4-9830-796e-ee8c5a1f41d4",
        },
        {
          title: "Nitrogen",
          key: "Nitrogen-c2922569-0b2d-0e07-454d-d8411af701b7",
        },
        {
          title: "Oxygen",
          key: "Oxygen-a3b8be32-c36e-a02e-37f4-a35239e0cedb",
        },
      ],
    }, ],
  },
  {
    title: "Planets",
    key: "33a3182b-93a4-84b9-4c49-c955a8416197",
    children: [{
      title: "Composition",
      key: "63b3d5cd12c06ba7ce353f76",
      children: [{
          title: "Chthonian planet",
          key: "Chthonian planet-b3c593c1-d29e-5e14-1b11-2241e8ef2be6",
        },
        {
          title: "Carbon planet",
          key: "Carbon planet-07d67d62-afcf-fbcf-a8e8-75081cb44c2f",
        },
      ],
    }, ],
  },
];

function filterChildrenById (item, ids) {
  if (item.children) {
    for (let i = 0; i < item.children.length; i++) {
      let child = item.children[i];
      if (ids.includes(child.key)) {
        item.children.splice(i, 1);
        // Reduce index because we removed an item so indexing will
        // be off if we don't do this
        i--;
      } else if (Array.isArray(child.children)) {
        child = filterChildrenById(child, ids);
      }
    }
  }
  return item;
}

function filterData(data, ids) {
  data.forEach(item => filterChildrenById(item, ids))
  return data;
}

console.log(
  " ~ file: TranferTree.misc.js:152 ~ onCheck ~ outputArray",
  filterData(originalArray, inputArray)
);
```

Comment: It's almost that but in `Elements` => `Non metals` you noticed that I removed only `Oxygen-a3b8be32-c36e-a02e-37f4-a35239e0cedb` not all objects

Comment: @Gabriel But the entire "Non metals" object should be removed since its key `633ac872e78fa7ebee03b8bf` is in the list, right?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I'll add your logic in my snippets, it's more detailed than mine, I'll probably use it in the future when dealing with more properties of this object. The error is why I was trying to `log` the `forEach` the correct is `originalArray`

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate from the end of the array, because `splice` changes index  for the followind item.

```js
const
    keys = ["Oxygen-a3b8be32-c36e-a02e-37f4-a35239e0cedb", "633ac872e78fa7ebee03b8bf", "5e69dbd7-5fee-67a9-c73f-4656f9b90715", "d484558b-4717-b0b8-db07-68288afb4f6a", "63922aac4ff08f52d71fa891", "33a3182b-93a4-84b9-4c49-c955a8416197"],
    data = [{ title: "Animals", key: "d484558b-4717-b0b8-db07-68288afb4f6a", children: [{ title: "Color", key: "63922aac4ff08f52d71fa891", children: [{ title: "Black", key: "Black-9e994ed2-823b-d1d6-4613-91d43f570fec" }, { title: "White", key: "White-5d0b102a-2555-8f7c-d471-cc82a5bd9c01" }] }] }, { title: "Elements", key: "5e69dbd7-5fee-67a9-c73f-4656f9b90715", children: [{ title: "Non metals", key: "633ac872e78fa7ebee03b8bf", children: [{ title: "Carbon", key: "Carbon-e443daa4-def4-9830-796e-ee8c5a1f41d4" }, { title: "Nitrogen", key: "Nitrogen-c2922569-0b2d-0e07-454d-d8411af701b7" }, { title: "Oxygen", key: "Oxygen-a3b8be32-c36e-a02e-37f4-a35239e0cedb" }] }] }, { title: "Planets", key: "33a3182b-93a4-84b9-4c49-c955a8416197", children: [{ title: "Composition", key: "63b3d5cd12c06ba7ce353f76", children: [{ title: "Chthonian planet", key: "Chthonian planet-b3c593c1-d29e-5e14-1b11-2241e8ef2be6" }, { title: "Carbon planet", key: "Carbon planet-07d67d62-afcf-fbcf-a8e8-75081cb44c2f" }] }] }],
    remove = keys => {
        const fn = array => {
            let i = array.length;
            while (i--) {
                if (keys.includes(array[i].key)) array.splice(i, 1);
                else if (array[i].children) fn(array[i].children);
            }
        };
        return fn;
    };

remove(keys)(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You don't technically *need* to iterate from the end, you could `i--` after removing the item in a traditional `for` loop, however this is the easier method if order doesn't matter

Comment: I also believe the OP doesn't want the top-level objects filtered, only the children and subsequent children